# Rename image before upload and insert name in database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, rename

I want image rename before upload and after renamed image name should be inserted into database with PHP. I am using following code to upload image and insert some other data into database. Please help me out to rename image because I'm beginner with PHP.

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $post_image = $_FILES['post_image']['name'];
    $post_image_tmp = $_FILES['post_image']['tmp_name'];
    $post_content = $_POST['post_content'];
    if ($post_image=='' OR $post_content=='') {
      echo "<script>alert('Fiil In All Fields')</script>";
    } else {
      move_uploaded_file($post_image_tmp, "../post_imgs/$post_image");
      $insert_post ="INSERT INTO posts(post_image,post_content)values('$post_image','$post_content')";
      $run_post= mysql_query($insert_post);
      echo "<script>alert('Post has been Published Now...')</script>";
      echo "<script>window.open('index.php?insert_post=insert','_self')</script>";
    }
  }

?>
```

Comment: Please edit the code by using 4 spaces in front of every line. This form is unreadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        $tmp_file = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'];
        $ext = pathinfo($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $rand = md5(uniqid().rand());
        $post_image = $rand.".".$ext;
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_file,"../post_imgs/".$post_image);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this..**

```
 <?php

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $post_image = $_FILES['post_image']['name'];
    $post_image_tmp = $_FILES['post_image']['tmp_name'];
    $post_content = $_POST['post_content'];
    if ($post_image=='' OR $post_content=='') {
      echo "<script>alert('Fiil In All Fields')</script>";
    } else {
    $newname="image".$post_image; 
    $path='../post_imgs/';
$pathAndName = $path.$newname;
$moveResult = move_uploaded_file($post_image_tmp, $pathAndName);//move to folder
 $insert_post ="INSERT INTO posts(post_image,post_content)values('$newname','$post_content')";
      $run_post= mysql_query($insert_post);
      echo "<script>alert('Post has been Published Now...')</script>";
      echo "<script>window.open('index.php?insert_post=insert','_self')</script>";
    }
  }

?>
```

Comment: Sir please please give me answer with my code ... Thanks

Comment: @Shaggy i have update my answer with your code .check it and let me know